# Spring Hibernate detached entity passed to persist, cascade issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, cascade

I have a big issue on saving some related entity.
I need to save multiple ElementaryFlowBase objects:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class ElementaryFlowBase {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private UUID id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_elementary_flow_category", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ElementaryFlowCategory category;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_elementary_flow_sub_category", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ElementaryFlowSubCategory subCategory;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
private SourceInfo sourceInfo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_uom", referencedColumnName = "id")
private UnitOfMeasure unitOfMeasure;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "elementaryFlowBase", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<BaseEnvironmentalImpact> coefficientFactors;

@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private String originalId;
}
```

Inside it there are different BaseEnvironmentalImpact(I use cascade to save them from the parents).

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class BaseEnvironmentalImpact {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private UUID id;
private double value;
private double normalizedValue;
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_methodology", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Methodology methodology;
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_impact_category", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ImpactCategory impactCategory;
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_impact_indicator", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ImpactIndicator impactIndicator;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
private SourceInfo sourceInfo;

@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private String originalId;

//ref
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_elementary_flow_base")
private ElementaryFlowBase elementaryFlowBase;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "process_base_id",
                referencedColumnName = "process_base_id"),
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "reference_product_id",
                referencedColumnName = "reference_product_id")
})
private ProcessTemplate processTemplate;
}
```

BaseEnvironmentalImpact have Methodology, ImpactCategory, ImpactIndicator (also these entities are related).

Methodology:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Methodology {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private UUID id;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "methodology", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<ImpactCategory> impactCategories;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
private SourceInfo sourceInfo;

@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private String originalId;
}
```

Impact Category:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class ImpactCategory {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private UUID id;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "impactCategory", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<ImpactIndicator> impactIndicators;

//ref
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_methodology", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Methodology methodology;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
private SourceInfo sourceInfo;

@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private String originalId;

}
```

ImpactIndicator:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class ImpactIndicator {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private UUID id;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_uom", referencedColumnName = "id")
private UnitOfMeasure unitOfMeasure;

//ref
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name= "fk_impact_category", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ImpactCategory impactCategory;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
private SourceInfo sourceInfo;

@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private String originalId;

}
```

Saving elementaryFlowBase I want to save using cascade all these entities.

With these settings I can save the first ElementaryFlowBase (using CrudRepository):

```
    @GetMapping("/elementaryflowbases")
    public String importElementaryFlowBases() {
    System.out.println("Elementary flow bases import started");

    Set<ElementaryFlowBase> items =  importer.getElementaryFlowBases();

    for (ElementaryFlowBase item : items){
        elementaryFlowBaseRepository.save(item);
    }
    return "Elementary flow bases has been imported: + " + items.size() + "elements!";
}
```

but on the second step of the for I have this error:

```
detached entity passed to persist: xxx.sp_model.sustainability.model.assessment.ImpactCategory
```

Methodology, ImpactCategory,ImpactIndicator could be the same for some BaseEnvironmentalImpact. But some BaseEnvironmentalImpact could have others Methodology, ImpactCategory,ImpactIndicator.
So with cascade I want to save or update(or use what's on db, it's the same for me).

What's wrong? Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

---

EDIT
the saveAll (without for cycle) solve the issue. But it was a test to see how to save or update things already on db. To better understand I have another object, called ProcessTemplate that has other BaseEnvironmentalImpact but that could use the same Methodology, ImpactCategory and ImpactIndicator:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class ProcessTemplate {
@EmbeddedId
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private ProcessTemplateId id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_process_base", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ProcessBase processBase;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_reference_flow_base", referencedColumnName = "id")
private FlowBase referenceProduct;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable(
        name="processtemplates_flowtemplates",
        joinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name = "process_base_id", referencedColumnName = "process_base_id"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "reference_product_id", referencedColumnName = "reference_product_id")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_flowtemplate", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<FlowTemplate> flowsTemplate;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Set<ElementaryFlowTemplate> elementaryFlowsTemplate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
private SourceInfo sourceInfo;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Validation validation;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Set<BaseEnvironmentalImpact> environmentalImpacts;

@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private String originalId;

@PrePersist
void id() {
    this.id = new ProcessTemplateId(processBase.getId(), referenceProduct.getId());
}
}
```

SaveAll solve the previous issue but here I have again the same problem.
So the suggestion seems to use transactional. Can I use it like that, because I used CrudRepository save method?

```
    @Transactional
    @GetMapping("/run")
public String run() {
    if(importer.runImporter() == 0){

        ...
        System.out.println(importElementaryFlowBases());
        System.out.println(importProcessTemplates());

        return "Import process has been executed";
    }
    else{
        return "Fail on import";
    }

}

public String importElementaryFlowBases() {
    System.out.println("Elementary flow bases import started");

    Set<ElementaryFlowBase> items =  importer.getElementaryFlowBases();
    elementaryFlowBaseRepository.saveAll(items);

    return "Elementary flow bases has been imported: + " + items.size() + "elements!";
}

public String importProcessTemplates() {
    System.out.println("Process templates import started");

    Set<ProcessTemplate> items =  importer.getProcessTemplates();

        processTemplateRepository.saveAll(items);
   
    return "Process templates has been imported: + " + items.size() + "elements!";
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `saveAll()` method instead saving one by one or I suggest to use  `@Transactional` annotation, so that all the saving operations happen in same transaction.

Comment: Thank you @krishnathota, the saveAll solve the showed issue but not my problem in general, please see the edit.

Comment: for `ProcessTemplate` you can fetch the required params from DB(findById() etc) and add them to the `ProcessTemplate` and save, no problem at all.